# python robobrowser trigger post from js

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess, python-requests

first of all, I log into a website www.example.com/login and the resulted website contains a script like following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    if ($('#UserLocationGroup option').size() <= 1) {
        $('#UserLocationGroup').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    $('#UserLocationGroup').change(function () {
        var areYouSure = true;
        if ($('form').length > 0) {
            areYouSure = $('form').triggerHandler('navigateaway');
        }
        if (areYouSure === false) {
            return;
        }
        $.post('/Users/set-role', $.extend({}, { id: $(this).val() }, aw.antiforgeryToken), function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            console.log('redirecting..' + data.redirectUrl);

        });
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("#UserLocationGroup > option").length == 1) {
        $("#UserLocationGroup").css("background-image", "none");
    }

    var usernameWithTrim = $('.js-tooltip-admin');
    var usernameWithoutTrim = $('.js-tooltip-light-admin');

    if (usernameWithoutTrim.width() <= usernameWithTrim.width()) {
        usernameWithoutTrim.hide();
    }

});
```

and there is dropdown menu which contains option1 option2 option3, when options get changed, the above js start sending a post to server (at least that's what i understand)

how do i mimic this post from robobrowser?

i have tried following

```
browser=RoboBrowser()
headers={'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest','User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.78 Safari/537.36'}
    browser.session.headers.update(headers)
    print browser.response.headers

    data={'id':role,'__RequestVerificationToken':token}
    encoded_data=urllib.urlencode(data)
```

browser.session.request('POST','https://example.com/Users/set-role',encoded_data,headers)

and this failed with no details error,

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out 
using browser.session.post(url,data) works now